# Devexpress make RibbonPageGroup Caption bold

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have such a Ribbon Page Group :

```
<dxr:RibbonPageGroup Name="newReports" Caption="New Reports">
```

I want the caption to look bold. How can I do that? I searched around the web but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting [RibbonControl.GroupCaptionTextStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfRibbonRibbonControl_GroupCaptionTextStyletopic).

From devexpress [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfRibbonRibbonPageGroup_Captiontopic):

> **Remarks**
>
> To apply a style to paint the caption in a custom manner, use RibbonControl.GroupCaptionTextStyle.

sample: [(taken from devexpress Support Center)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q503062)

```
<dxr:RibbonPageGroup Name="newReports" Caption="New Reports">
    <dxr:RibbonControl.GroupCaptionTextStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>
    </dxr:RibbonControl.GroupCaptionTextStyle>
</dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't do what you said. Could you give an example if possible?

Comment: try the sample. i don't have devexpress to compile the code, though